Topological Sort as Reverse Post-DFS | Course Schedule II LeetCode
Currently solving Course Schedule II on LeetCode and this is the code that DOES NOT pass all test cases because of the following line: Collections.reverse(postOrder);. Removing this line solves all test cases.
class Solution {
    public int[] findOrder(int numCourses, int[][] prerequisites) {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();

        for (int[] pre: prerequisites) {
            graph.put(pre[0], new ArrayList<>());
        }
        
        for (int[] pre: prerequisites) {
            graph.get(pre[0]).add(pre[1]);
        }

        boolean visited[] = new boolean[numCourses];
        boolean visiting[] = new boolean[numCourses];

        ArrayList<Integer> postOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++) {
            if (!visited[i]) {
                if (!dfs(i, visited, visiting, postOrder, graph)) {
                    return new int[0];
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.reverse(postOrder);
        return postOrder.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();

    }

    private boolean dfs(Integer v, boolean[] visited, boolean[] visiting, ArrayList<Integer> postOrder, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> graph) {
        visiting[v] = true;

        if (graph.get(v) != null) {
            for (Integer neighbor : graph.get(v)) {
                if(visiting[neighbor]) {
                    return false;
                }
                
                if (!visited[neighbor]) {
                    if (!dfs(neighbor, visited, visiting, postOrder, graph)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        

        visiting[v] = false;
        visited[v] = true;
        
        postOrder.add(v);
        System.out.println(v);
        return true;
    }
}


I learned that a reverse of post-order DFS produces a valid topological sort. However, when I reverse my DFS post-order list, I get the incorrect answer. I pass all the test cases without the reversal. Does anyone know why this is the case? I appreciate any insights.
This is the main() code for reproducing the incorrect answer:
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Solution solution = new Solution();
    
            // Test case 1
            int numCourses1 = 3;
            int[][] prerequisites1 = {{1, 0}};
            int[] result1 = solution.findOrder(numCourses1, prerequisites1);
            printResult(result1);
    
            // Test case 2
            int numCourses2 = 3;
            int[][] prerequisites2 = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 0}};
            int[] result2 = solution.findOrder(numCourses2, prerequisites2);
            printResult(result2);
        }
    
        private static void printResult(int[] result) {
            if (result.length == 0) {
                System.out.println("No valid course order.");
            } else {
                for (int course : result) {
                    System.out.print(course + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

As a result of Test Case 2, the answer my code gives is the reverse of the actual answer.

Please provide the code that doesn't work, and please add the code to call your function with actual input, so that it is reproducible.

@trincot Just made those changes, thank you in advance for your help!


I learned that a reverse of post-order DFS produces a valid topological sort.

If you reverse a post-order sequence, then you get a pre-order. For example, if you have this (dependency) tree, where a needs b, e and f, ...etc:
         a
       / | \
      b  e  f
     / \   /|\
    c   d g h i

Then the post order sequence is:
c d b e g h i f a

Reversed:
a f i h g e b d c

This means you will now start at the root, and visit the dependencies in the reversed (i.e. wrong) order: a should not be the first in the output, since it is dependent on several other nodes.
Possibly you've heard that you can use a post-order sequence where the children of a node are visited in reversed order. For the example that would be:
i h g f e d c b a

This would work fine.

So to clarify, a normal post-order DFS produces a valid topological sort? @trincot
The contradictory part, for example, is this link that says that 'Topological ordering is the reverse of the postorder': https://joshhug.gitbooks.io/hug61b/content/chap21/chap211.html

Yes, by definition a post order traversal only visits a node when all its children have been visited, which for the given challenge translates to listing a course's requirements before the course itself is listed.

Now, the ambiguity here is how you define your graph. If the parent-child relation is to mean that the parent requires the child, then it is as you have designed the graph, and a postorder will do the trick. If however you define the parent-child relation to mean that the children are dependent on the parent, then you can achieve the result with a reversed postorder traversal. It is a matter of what a directed edge means in your graph.

Did this answer your question?

Yes, thank you so much! I appreciate it. @trincot

Great! It would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted. Optional though!
